# MATLAB Extract all rows between two variables with a threshold

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array called BodyData in MATLAB that has around 139 columns and 3500 odd rows of skeletal tracking data.
I need to extract all rows between two string values (these are timestamps when an event happened) that I have
e.g.

```
BodyData{}= 
Column 1             2       3   
'10:15:15.332'   'BASE05'   ... 
...
'10:17:33:230'   'BASE05'   ...
```

The two timestamps should match a value in the array but might also be within a few ms of those in the array e.g.

```
TimeStamp1 = '10:15:15.560'
TimeStamp2 = '10:17:33.233'
```

I have several questions!

How can I return an array for all the data between the two string values plus or minus a small threshold of say .100ms?

Also can I also add another condition to say that all str values in column2 must also be the same, otherwise ignore? For example, only return the timestamps between A and B only if 'BASE02'

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to the first part of your problem is probably to change from strings to numeric date values. In Matlab this can be done quite painlessly with `datenum`.

For the second part you can just use logical indexing... this is were you put a condition (i.e. that second columns is `BASE02`) within the indexing expression.

A self-contained example:

```
% some example data:
BodyData = {'10:15:15.332', 'BASE05', 'foo';... 
            '10:15:16.332', 'BASE02', 'bar';... 
            '10:15:17.332', 'BASE05', 'foo';... 
            '10:15:18.332', 'BASE02', 'foo';... 
            '10:15:19.332', 'BASE05', 'bar'};

% create column vector of numeric times, and define start/end times
dateValues = datenum(BodyData(:, 1), 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');
startTime = datenum('10:15:16.100', 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');
endTime = datenum('10:15:18.500', 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');

% select data in range, and where second column is 'BASE02'
BodyData(dateValues > startTime & dateValues < endTime & strcmp(BodyData(:, 2), 'BASE02'), :)
```

Returns:

```
ans =
'10:15:16.332' 'BASE02' 'bar'
'10:15:18.332' 'BASE02' 'foo'
```

References: [datenum manual page](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), [matlab help page on logical indexing](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).